# What is Solo Showdown in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have played Solo Showdown before, BUT i dont see the diffrence between  that and Solo?

The description  says that its for "high skill players". Why? It looks the same as Solo.

What is Solo Showdown, and what's special about this mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Solo Showdown](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/solo-showdown-limited-time-mode?sessionInvalidated=true) Queue up for the Solo Showdown mode for a hotly contested Battle Royale experience. Unlike other LTMs, Solo Showdown will not change core gameplay of the current Solo mode. Instead, you will be placed against other self-selected competitors making this the ultimate test of survival.
>
> The Fortnite team will frequently update this blog with the Solo Showdown standings. Top performers will be rewarded at the conclusion of this competition.

The rewards are as follows:

```
1st Place:  50,000 V-Bucks

2nd - 4th  Place:  25,000 V-Bucks

5th – 50th Place:  13,500 V-Bucks

51st – 100th Place:  7,500 V-Bucks
```

> Your first 50 matches in the Solo Showdown LTM will be counted towards your Score. You can see the full rules [here](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/solo-showdown-contest-rules).

It is essentially Fortnite's way of selecting who will be appearing at the next tournament, as well as a competitive edge when there are no rankings, ladders, seasons, etc.

Comment: What did you mean by *the next tournament*?

Comment: @TBNRBlur Fortnite is hosting multiple tournaments over the summer for a cash prize.

Comment: I know, I was wondering if there was another tournament because you said *Your first **50** matches*. The new one is 25 matches